# Unable to install django, i get JWT error

Tags: python, django, rest

When I try to install django (on Google cloud) I get this message:

```
    File "/root/lplatform/back/lplatform_api/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView, TokenVerifyView
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework_simplejwt'
```

this is my url.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('lplatform_api.urls'))
]
```

and this is my setting.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
,        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

When i do pip freeze i get the list below, i think that all needed dependencies are present in the virtual env:

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0
cryptography==2.1.4
Django==1.11.29
djangorestframework==3.9.4
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.1.4
enum34==1.1.6
idna==2.6
ipaddress==1.0.17
keyring==10.6.0
keyrings.alt==3.0
pycrypto==2.6.1
pygobject==3.26.1
PyJWT==1.7.1
pytz==2019.3
pyxdg==0.25
SecretStorage==2.3.1
six==1.11.0
```

Comment: https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#installation I would read through this section on the documentation on using the JWT plugin with Django Rest Frameworks and also be sure that your requirements.txt has all the supporting pip installs for your “Google” deployment

Comment: Check your `INSTALLED_APPS`. You maybe missed something like `,`

Comment: @kyore I added my pip freeze in an edit.

Comment: Show `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings.py

Comment: @kyore here is my installed_apps `INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'lplatform_api',
]`